# wallpapers for ubuntu, paint app

Tags: c, desktop-background, compiler, paint

I want to have new wallpapers for ubuntu desktop. How to get them, where?

Also what is paintbrush app named in ubuntu. In windows it is mspaint.

Is C compiler available from software centre?

Comment: Please post one question per form.

Comment: GNU C Compiler is included in Ubuntu. You can just simple install a text-editor like Sublime Text and compile and run C programs from within it. Or you can use gedit to write programs and compile them from terminal using gcc.

Answer (score 1):

For wallpapers, install Wallch software,its available in software centre. Then download wallpapers from the net, open Wallch, Add the folder where the wallpapers are to wallch "Add Folder" option, set the timing and click start,and you'l get a wallpaper slideshow.For a single wallpaper, just right click on the image and select set as desktop.
There are several apps which allows you to not only paint but even photoshop like- GIMP , GNU paint . Both are available in software centre.

Answer (score 0):

Just image search for wallpapers and right-click them and choose set as background image (or something like that).

Maybe gimp helps you out, although it offers more possibilities than mspaint.

I dont know about compilers etc, but a quick search showed me this, maybe it helps you:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/protobuf-c-compiler